# Loop on a promise indefinitely until rejection

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, es6-promise

I have a function that does some async work and returns a `Promise`, and I want to execute this function indefinitely until the promise is `reject`ed.

Something like the following :

```
doSomethingAsync().
    .then(doSomethingAsync)
    .then(doSomethingAsync)
    .then(doSomethingAsync)
    // ... until rejection
```

I made a little CodePen so I can test potential solutions : http://codepen.io/JesmoDrazik/pen/pbAovZ?editors=0011

I found several potential answers but nothing seems to work for my case.

If anyone has a solution, I'd be glad, because I just can't find anything !

Thanks.

Comment: Your setTimeout and the button comments in your codepen make me wonder what you're really trying to achieve. It's possible promises aren't what you need. Clicking a button doesn't result in a rejection in the promises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
(function loop(){
     doSomethingAsync().then(loop);
})();
```

But looking at your pen it's not clear where the rejection should come from. If you want to stop repeating an operation when the user clicks a button, you can change a state in the button handling and then do

```
(function loop(){
     doSomethingAsync().then(function(){
          if (!stopped) loop();
     });
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Made a modification to your [codepen](http://codepen.io/kriddy800/pen/GqvRwk?editors=1011)

```
var FAKE_COUNT = 0;

function doSomething() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('doing something async: ' + FAKE_COUNT)
      if (FAKE_COUNT < 10) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
      FAKE_COUNT ++;
    }, 1000);
  });
}

const button = document.querySelector('.js-button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // maybe we can do something here ?
})

function test() {
  doSomething().then(test).catch(() => {
    console.log("Rejected")
  });
}

test();
```

FAKE_COUNT just becomes the flag, so if you want to stop the promise with a click instead of a count you could just make it a bool and check that when executing the async task

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where you want the logic and rejection to take place, but assuming you want the promise itself to be self executing (otherwise the asynchronous execution itself could loop) it could return itself as a new promise:

```
function doSomething() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('doing something async');
        resolve();
    }, 1000);
  }).then(()=>doSomething());
}
```

For the rejection part, the easiest way would be to introduce a flag, (although that would make the promise a little less self containing):

```
var stop = false;
function doSomething() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if(stop)
        reject();
    else{
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('doing something async');
        resolve(); //(check for stop could be done here as well)
      }, 1000);
    }
  }).then(()=>doSomething());
}

const button = document.querySelector('.js-button');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  stop = true;
});

doSomething();
```